# Extract Year/Month From List If In Specific Quarter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a list of months that match the specific quarter from a list of historical months. The following is what the list looks like.

```
Column A
2022 October
2022 December
2023 January
2023 March
2023 May
2023 June
2023 August
2024 September
2023 October
2023 December
2024 February
2024 March
```

I've used the following formula to figure out what quarter the month belongs to but I would have to do this to each, possibly with a helper column and then a filter with multiple conditions.

`=LEFT(A2, SEARCH(" ", A2)-1) &CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(MATCH(RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2) - SEARCH(" ",A2)), {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"},0)/3,0),"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")`

I'm trying to do this all with one formula without a helper column. Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Other Notes:

- There will only ever be 2 months per quarter so the list will only be two entries long.
- I'd like the input to be in this format "2024Q1" in cell D2. So I would need the months corresponding to that quarter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using FILTER:

```
=FILTER(A1:A12,D1=LEFT(A1:A12,4)&"Q"&INT((MONTH(1&MID(A1:A12,6,15))-1)/3+1))
```

[image]

`1&MID(A1:A12,6,15)` creates a string of `1` and the Month name.  Then MONTH() turns that to a true date for this year and returns the MONTH number.  Which means this only works if the Month name matches your local language for the month name, or it will not convert correctly.

Comment: This worked well. Just so I can wrap my head around this can you explain the portiono of the formula that starts with ```INT```? That portion is looking for the quarter based on the month name, right? As you mentioned you added a 1 to the Mid formula... I guess I'm still not understanding how that works.

Comment: `1&MID(A1:A12,6,15)` will create a string like `1February` When combined with MONTH it turns that string to a real date equal to `2024-02-01`.  It then returns the month number which in this case is `2` then we subtract `1` to make it `1` then divide by `3` which is `0.333333` then add `1` to get `1.3333` and take just the integer part or `1` to get the quarter. we have to subtract `1` to make March in the first quarter.

Comment: Very slick. Never would have thought of that.